# jqplot : How to change axes ticks formatString after zooming

Tags: jquery, graph, jqplot

How can I re-set ticks's formatString after a zoom operation?

I'm using `$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer` plugin on "xaxis" with `formatString = "%d.%m"`, but when I zoom I'd like to change it in something like `%d.%m %H:%M:%S` according to new min and max values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I have something for you.
[Please see the sample for code details.](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/BLfRe/)

The whole problem comes down to overwriting the `DateTickFormatter` with this code:

```
    $.jqplot.DateTickFormatter = function(format, val) {
        if (plot) {
            var noDays = days_between(new Date(plot.axes.xaxis.max), new Date(plot.axes.xaxis.min));
            console.log("days_between = " + noDays);

            if (noDays < 28) format = "%d";
            else if (noDays < 120) format = '%m/%d';
            else format = '%Y/%m/%d';
        }
        return $.jsDate.strftime(val, format);
    };
```

It will return different format depending on the number of visible days. Play with the code and see what happens when you zoom.